# Dreamweaver: background-image set at height: auto will show no content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, dreamweaver, fluid-layout

I've read quite a number of questions here today to hopefully answer my question with no avail, so I hope someone here can help me.

I am trying to evolve my website to a responsive web design, and am having issue with the images.

Issue:

I am trying to load the images from my css labeled as background-images, but since there is no content in the containers I am loading them in, setting the height at auto will result in no picture since the container is technically at 0 without any content. I need to set the height at auto because I need the image to scale with the webpage so that it will stay proportional without large empty white spaces.

I understand to have my background image scale, I will have to set my css to this:

```
background: url(../images/image.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
```

Again, the reason why this does not work for me is because I am looking to use the background image as an actual image without any content over it. Since there is no content, the image will not show. What I want to know is if there is a way around this issue.

The reason why I am choosing to load images through css is because I want to be able to load multiple versions (small to large file size scaled towards specific device size) of a particular image based on the viewers device (desktop, mobile phone, tablet, etc).

Just to cover all grounds, I want to mention that I have used the img tag in the html and have it rescale for different devices through css. However, if it is possible, I would like to still load the image through css as it will allow me to load different file sizes for different device sizes to enhance user experience from mobile devices. If there is another way to do this, please advise. I have spent 26 working hours on this so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I have started a test template to keep the coding simple so everyone can see what I'm working with, and maybe help diagnose why it isn't working.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="cache" />
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Enter Keywords" />
<meta name="description" content="Description Here" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/s.ico" >



<meta id="view" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/stylesheet_ie.css" />
<![endif]-->


</head>

<body>

    <div class="page">

        <div class="page_content">

                <div class="contentmain"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
</body>


</html>
```

My CSS:

```
/* This stylesheet was designed and developed by Chris Converse, Codify Design Studio */

@charset "UTF-8";

/* Text Formatting */

body {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 20px;
color: #555;
background: url(../images/back.jpg)
}


.page { font-size: 1em; background-color: #FFF; }

h1 { font-size: 2em; color: #9e472a; margin: 0px 0px .5em 0px; font-weight: normal; }
h2 { font-size: 1.6em; color: #9e472a; margin: 0px 0px .5em 0px; }
h3 { font-size: 1.25em; color: #9e472a; margin: 0em 0px .25em 0px; }
p { margin: 0px 0px 1em 0px; font-size: 1em; }
li { margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px; }
a img { border: none; }
a { color: #f52d1b; }
a:hover { color: #00a2ed; }




/* Layout */

.page { position: relative; margin: 0px auto 0px auto; max-width: 980px; }


.page .page_content { background-color: #fff; padding: 1px 0px 1px 0px; }

.page .page_content .page_content_container_main { width: 100%; float: left; margin:     0px; padding: 0px;  }


.page .page_content .content {
margin: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
padding: 0px;

}


.page .page_content .contentmain {


background: url(../images/mimg-l.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
background-size: 100% 100% contain;
```

An example of what I am trying to achieve can be found at www.dreamcreationstudios.com/test2.html. This is done through the img tag. I am hoping to be able to create the same effect except load the image through css instead so that I can load cropped versions of the original image in various screen sizes. Thank you.

Comment: `height: auto` will only work if you have content. Without any, the element will  not show any height. You have to explicitly set the height of the element

Comment: In light of what I'm trying to do, what would you suggest to accomplish it? Essentially, I want an image that would scale to device size, and at the same time be able to load an image in multiple sizes based on the screen size of the viewer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by applying a padding-bottom on the div with the background-image but you must know the aspect ratio of the image first.

```
.page .page_content .contentmain {
    background: url(../images/mimg-l.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 0; //Make the div 0px high
    padding-bottom: 75%; //Adjust this value to match the image dimensions
    background-size: 100% 100% contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set a minimum height for the content container, such that the container will not collapse to a height of 0 when there is no content: `min-height` would work for you.

Alternatively, you can set the background-image on a parent element who already has a defined height.

p/s: If you don't want ugly white spaces because the background fails to cover the entire container, then you should use `background-size: cover`. You will preserve the aspect ratio of the image, and the browser will scale the background image accordingly such that it's shortest axis will stretch as far as it is required to cover the container entirely.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The issue for me is that if I set the min-height, the webpage would not scale properly when the browser is being sized down, and using the background-size: cover would work, but only if my container has content. I was hoping to be able to use background-image through css as regular display images without any content over them to allow more versatility to the webpages that I'm trying to create. If this is suppose to work and I'm doing something wrong, please let me know. I will post the code of which I'm working with.

Comment: If you still want to show an image when there is no textual content, then you should use the `<img>` tag instead, no? And it's a bit hard to do both - maintaining scale when sizing down /yet/ keeping a minimum height. You have to provide more context of the design you're working on, or else we are all having our hands tied.

Comment: Ted, I have posted my html code and css code in my original post. I have also uploaded a sample of the webpage which can be found at www.dreamcreationstudios.com/test2.html. The logo and stuff will look wacky, but keep in mind this is just a test page. In that test page, I used the image tag in the html and defined it in css which allows the image to scale while keeping the webpage proportional. This is what I want to achieve, however, what I am looking for is a way to load different file sized version of that image based on the width of the screen in which it is loaded from.

Comment: My thinking is that by loading the image through css, I am able to dictate which image file to load based on the viewer's screen size to reduce bandwidth consumption and produce faster load times. I don't know of a way to do this through the img tag in html so if there is, please let me know.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more, if you go to my test page, you will find that there are 3 layouts. One at full screen, one at min-width of 501px to max-width of 800px, and one from min-width: 150px - max-width 500px. What I want to do is load a cropped version of the original image in each of those respective screen sizes. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the "proportional" idea that you have in mind? I simply don't get it - what is proportional and what is not?

Comment: Terry, I want the footer of the page to stay just beneath the image as it is scaling down. If you go to my test site at www.dreamcreationstudios.com/test2.html, it achieves just that. However, the method I used is not bandwidth friendly and I would like to be able to load different images depending on the screen size of the viewer. So what I want to know is how do I get the webpage to load different images based on the screen size if I am using img tags in my html? Thanks

Comment: Sticky footer? Use this - http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/. Trying to achieve the same aspect ratio over different screen sizes is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole bunch of hacks to do in a responsive manner. it not a fault of Dreamweaver.
By default Browser looks on your code and check whether there is any blank element that does't  have any child element or itself with a width and height defined.
You have defined its width that is good but unfortunately it didn't get any height of this container. 
The best and fast way to do this is to define its `background-size` property, don't worry about container's height.

```
background: url(../images/image.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%; // example, you can change it.
```

And it'll work perfectly in all devices.

Comment: I've also tried this route but to no avail. Might it be because I'm using CS5 and not CS5.5 or 6?

Comment: Akshaya, I've just updated my post to show you my code. I copied and pasted the properties you listed here, but it seems that the css is still only responding to the lack of content. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Just try with a sample div block. I've tried and it works perfectly.         <style>
  div{
    width:100%;
    background: url("image.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    min-height: 5em;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
  }
</style>

  <div>
    
  </div>

Comment: Akshaya, thank you for your response. I really appreciate it. Now bare with me, as I am in no way an advance user of Dreamweaver. Suppose I put the above code in my html to load my background image, is there a code that can be used with this to load a different image file based on the viewer's screen size?

Comment: I've uploaded a test site so you can see what I'm trying to do. The URL is www.dreamcreationstudios.com/test2.html. When you minimize the browser all the way, you will see I have created 3 different layouts to accommodate different screen sizes and the image scales to all 3 perfectly. What I am trying to do is have it load a different version of the image for each layout, perhaps a cropped and less bandwidth intensive versions of the image as the site is being scaled down. Thats what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks